# DRF post url without end slash

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

In my application , I need to display the REST url(s) without a slash at the end. I have tried below combination but it didnt work.

Added `APPEND_SLASH=True` in the settings.py

and on the urls.py file

```
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter
router = SimpleRouter(trailing_slash=False)
```

After adding this when I am calling the urls without slash at the end in the postman, it is giving me an 404 error- URL not found. But with slash at the end is working fine.

Is there any option to make this url without with slash at the end ? Especially for the post urls

Comment: Did you restart web server? Can you add full url.py file?

Comment: Yes I did . webserver restart

Answer (score 2):

[APPEND_SLASH](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#append-slash) will append it to the request (e.g. mysite/blog --> mysite/blog/). This is not what you want, since your urlconf explicitly says there should be no slash.

Also APPEND_SLASH is True by default. So you need to set it to False instead. That way, if you make a request without a slash, Django won't automatically add in a slash.